# CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern broken in .Net 3.5?

Tags: .net, datetime, .net-4.0, .net-3.5, cultureinfo

In Windows 7 Region and Language settings, my overall "Format" is set to "English (United States)", but my individual patterns for dates & times are set as follows...

Long date: `dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy`

Short date: `MM/dd/yyyy`

Long time: `HH:mm:ss`

Short time: `HH:mm`

When I run the following, targeted at .Net 4.0

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongDatePattern);
  Console.WriteLine(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern);
  Console.WriteLine(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern);
  Console.WriteLine(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortTimePattern);
}
```

I end up with results as you'd expect,

```
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy
MM/dd/yyyy
HH:mm:ss
HH:mm
```

But if I run it targeted at .Net 3.5 (or below), I get:

```
dddd, dd MMMM, yyyy
MM/dd/yyyy
HH:mm:ss
h:mm tt
```

You'll notice that the long time format uses my chosen windows format, but the short one seems to use the default for "English (United States)".

Am I overlooking something?

Comment: .NET support for custom formats was out of sync with the Windows support.  Fairly inevitable with it needing to support old operating systems like Windows 98 and 2000.  It all got fixed with Windows 7 and .NET 4.  Progress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that this is a known issue in .NET 3.5. See [this Microsoft Connect feedback item](https://web.archive.org/web/20120730223628/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/167791/datetime-now-tostring-t-not-following-custom-regional-settings).

The feedback includes a suggested workaround.